How to write sort by key function in ballerina?
string[] arr = ['abcd-4', 'abcd-1', 'abcd-3', 'abcd-2']
Here is my list. I need this array to be get sorted by the key as the last number after '-'. I know there is a sort function in ballerina but how to add this requirement to the function.
I tried
string[] sortedProducts = products.sort("descending", function set(string str) returns int {
...
})

But it is not working.

Here is another way to meet your requirements using language-integrated query expressions.
import ballerina/lang.regexp;

public function main() {
    string[] arr = ["abcd-4", "abcd-1", "abcd-3", "abcd-2"];

    regexp:RegExp regex = re `-`;
    string[] sorted = from var e in arr
        let var k = regex.split(e)[1]
        order by k descending
        select e;

    io:println(sorted);
}


Below code will solve your problem.
import ballerina/lang.array;
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    string[] array = ["abcd-4", "abcd-1", "abcd-3", "abcd-2"];

    string[] sortedArray = array.sort(array:DESCENDING, isolated function (string a) returns  string {
        return re `-`.split(a)[1];
    });

    io:println(sortedArray);
}

If you want to use a custom sorting logic, you can pass an isolated function as an argument to the same sort() function.
